# Toggle WMS layer on/off with own button click on leaflet

Tags: jquery, leaflet

I've created a few maps and now i would like to publish them using leaflet and geoserver. Everything is working fine, i can change the layers using layer control, but i want to do that using my own buttons. The problem is that i cant figure out how. I have all the buttons created , and i just want to create a function that adds the wms tile layer to the map on click

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is what i tried so far but it doesnt work:

```
function appear(){
    var floodToday = L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms", {
        layers: 'FloodlayerWMS',
        format:'image/png',
        version: '1.1.1',
        transparent: true
    })
    map.addLayer(floodToday);
}
$(".WToday").on("click",appear);
```

I found this answer already:[Hide/Show layerGroups in Leaflet with own Buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658596/hide-show-layergroups-in-leaflet-with-own-buttons) but it hasn't proved useful. I'm guessing my problems are connected to the use of wms tile layers but i'm not sure how to go around it.

**UPDATE**

@HudsonPH's answer was a bit to complicated for me as I have almost no knowledge in Javascript and JQuery but after fiddling around with the code a bit and trying different options this is what works for me:

```
$("#WToday").click(function(event) {
    var floodToday = L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms", {
    layers: 'FloodlayerWMS',
    format:'image/png',
    version: '1.1.1',
    transparent: true
    })
map.addLayer(floodToday);
});
```

Thank you all for trying to help me.

Comment: Have you tried using a non-wms layer for testing?

Comment: @IvanSanchez: no, but i think the problem is with the on click event triggering the function. When i set the function on timeout it works fine. the problem seems to be the fact that it does not register the click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use trim to compare the names and trigger a event.
Obs: I used data-attribute to get the value

```
 $("[name='leaflet-base-layers']").parent().each(function (index) {
            $layerControl = $(this);
            if ($that.attr("Your-Date-Attribute").trim() == $layerControl.find("span").text().trim()) {                                  
                $(this).find("input").trigger("click");
            }
        });
```

Comment: i'm not really experienced with javascript and jquery, so i dont really understand what you did there. Could you please explain what you are doing here and i can try implementing it and ill let you know how it goes

Comment: You need to learn js and jquery if you dont know you cant extend anything, leaflet have a option to extend the class(this is the heart of everthing).
[Js](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp) ,
[Jquery](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp)