# Toggle marker visibility

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have marker layer in leaflet map, and I want to hide several markers based on feature property, but I can not see any method in leaflet documentation to do so.

Simplified my marker layer is like:

```
L.geoJson(data, {
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
        return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
            color: feature.properties.Color,
        });
    }
}).addTo(markersLayer);
```

PS. I use leaflet stable (0.7)

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658596/hide-show-layergroups-in-leaflet-with-own-buttons

Comment: Nope, I don't want to hide layer. I control my layers from layerControl. I want to hide individual markers (for example, but not necessarily, based on feature property in geojson source)

Answer (score -1):

Toggle the marker's container visibility:

```
marker._container.style.visibility = "visible"
```

or

```
marker._container.style.visibility = "hidden"
```

Comment: Well I log from my marker ref but I see no property called _container